# Javascript function not loading xml properly

Tags: javascript, html, xml

Hey guys, I've looked around online and on here a fair amount in order to try and figure out what the problem with this is. I am a newbie to anything not html, and I can not figure out why this XML is not loading.

Say I just have two files, "/contact.xml" and "/xmltest.html" and I want to load the xml into the html page using javascript. Here is what I have so far.

```
<html>
<body>
<h1>Carney Contacts Test</h1>
<b>Name:</b> <span id="name"></span><br />
<b>Email:</b> <span id="email"></span><br />
<b>Phone:</b> <span id="number"></span>

<script type="text/javascript">
var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();

xmlhttp.open("GET","contacts.xml",false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;

document.getElementById("name").innerHTML=
xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;

document.getElementById("email").innerHTML=
xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("email")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;

document.getElementById("phone").innerHTML=
xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("phone")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
</script>

</body>
```

Much of this was directly off the w3c site, and I still can not get it to work! Chrome is giving me "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getElementsByTagName' of null", if that helps anyone.

Help appreciated!

Comment: What doesn't work exactly? Does the request fire? Have you considered using a library like jQuery to fix cross-browser compatibility issues?

Comment: Are you using Firefox? Load the XML page manually, and see if your traversing is correct, and return the correct value. And don't forget that .firstChild is a simpler way to write .childNodes[0]

Answer (score 1):

You missed the next part on the site (I suppose by "w3c" you mean w3schools.com):

```
if (window.DOMParser)
  {
  parser=new DOMParser();
  xmlDoc=parser.parseFromString(text,"text/xml");
  }
else // Internet Explorer
  {
  xmlDoc=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
  xmlDoc.async="false";
  xmlDoc.loadXML(text);
  }
```

The XML text needs to be loaded into a DOM parser; in your above code, `xmlDoc` is just an arbitrary variable without any DOM parsing abilities.

But I *guess* the first problem is that you're maybe just opening the HTML file via the local file system - in that case your XML document will never be loaded, because an `XMLHttpRequest` only works via HTTP; it can only load stuff from a web server, not from the file system (which is why the responseXML is null, as the browser reports).

Comment: Er, W3C (w3.org) is the organisation that produced the DOM spec and many other web standards. W3Schools is an independent web site full of error-prone documentation and poor-quality tutorials, whose name seems to imply a relationship with W3C where there is none. Anyhow, getting the `reponseXML` DOM from a `XMLHttpRequest` is more cross-browser reliable than manual XML parsing; the question is just why the property has unexpectedly come back as null.

Comment: Yes, I know about W3C and W3Schools. The property has come back as `null` most probably because the OP tried to execute an `XMLHttpRequest` without HTTP, i.e. the `xmltest.html` page was not called from an actual web server.

Comment: Ohk, thanks guys. I had figured it had something to do with opening it locally, because i found some documentation of that online but could not fully understand it. However, I did figure that much out.

Answer (score 0):

How are you serving `contacts.xml`? Check it gets an appropriate `Content-Type` for XML, eg `text/xml`.

If you aren't serving `contacts.xml` at all, but just accessing it from the file system, well, that's your problem. Some browsers (Chrome, IE with native XMLHttpRequest) don't allow a web page on the filesystem to read other documents from the filesystem, as it's a clear security risk. Open up the JS console in Chrome's developer tools and you'll see the explanatory error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///.../contacts.xml. Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP.

Chuck your files on a local web server and it should work fine.

Comment: Ok, thanks to everyone for helping me out. But now, I am having a problem with the content-type. When I add the DOMParser code in, I get an error telling me that text is not defined. How can I fix this?

Comment: You've used a variable `text` without assigning it from anything (eg `xhr.responseText`). But, don't use DOMParser. Use the `responseXML` document.